# Gulp ESLinter do not report warnings

Tags: gulp, eslint, circleci

I'm using Gulp as part of my build process to run ESLinter,
my build fails due to warnings reported by ESLinter.

I would like to ignore / drop warnings at this stage, reading the docs i've found the quiet flag which should do just that, problem is adding quiet: true to my .eslintrc file doesn't seems to have any effect.

UPDATE:

The solution I've came up with was to read .eslintrc into a variable and expand it with quiet = true
then pass this object to eslint.

```
var strConfig = fs.readFileSync('./.eslintrc', 'utf8');
var config = JSON.parse(strConfig);
config.quiet = true;

const stream = gulp.src(['LIST_OF_FILES'])
    .pipe(eslint(config));

return stream.pipe(eslint.format('junit', function (result) {
    fs.writeFile('./output/eslint-out.xml', result);
}))
.pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```

Comment: I only see --quiet documented for use with eslint CLI. http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#quiet I was hoping for way to add to package.json to run eslint from CLI, I'm currently running from a SH script.